# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, retrofit

I created Retrofit interface

```java
public interface UserService {
@GET(Constants.Api.URL_LOGIN)
Call<String> loginUser(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String pass, @Query("secret") String secret, @Query("device_id") String deviceid, @Query("pub_key") String pubkey, @Query("device_name") String devicename);
```

When in Activity I call

```java
final Call<String> responce = 
  service.loginUser(loginedt.getText().toString(), md5(passwordedt.getText().toString()), secret, device_id, pub_key, device_name);

responce.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<String> response) {
        if (response.code() == Constants.Status.ERROR_404) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_log_pass), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (response.code() != Constants.Status.ERROR_404 && response.code() != Constants.Status.SUCCES) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.wrong_request), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
                       
    }
});
```

I am getting error

> onFailure java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Usually these kind of errors are because of GSon can't parse your json from your objects. Post your models for User too. Let's see if everything is correct

Comment: I don't post any objects. @Query Strings only

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but I think that you will need an entity class to work with retrofit. The reason is that internally it uses Gson and if you don't have any entity class Retrofit does not know how to parse POST,GET data

Answer (score 12):

If you don't create your own models, use `Call<JsonObject>`.

This is the default parser for application/json content type requests.

Comment: Thanks you saved me

Answer (score 4):

What is the response of your API? Retrofit parses the server response into the type passed to call object, i.e. `Call<ResponseType>`. As from error you are receiving, server returns object while you're expecting a string. 
 change your service to be

```
Call<ResponseTypeObject> loginUser(@Query("email") String email, @Query("password") String pass, @Query("secret") String secret, @Query("device_id") String deviceid, @Query("pub_key") String pubkey, @Query("device_name") String devicename);
```

where `ResponseTypeObject` is the response entity as returned from server

Answer (score 3):

Such error occurs whenever the Gson converter fails to parse the Json object from the server to the expected return type(in your case, which is a String). In such case, change the return type from `Call<String>` to `Call<ResponseBody>`.